# Multiple NSViews into one Xib file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, iboutlet, nsviewcontroller

For a couple of days, I have been trying to figure out how to work with multiple NSViews into a single .xib file. I have added a `NSViewController` subclass which I am using as my main controller, it has two `NSView`s with outlets for two custom views. I subclassed it into two NSViewController (PumpController & TransactionController) to control the content of both custom views.

I can get half a result when I bind the view of the MainController (File's owner) to one of the custom views. Then, when i call [self.view addSubview:SomeStuff] into one of the NSViewController, I get the right result but only in the view I connected the file's owner with. I need to get result in both views but I can't have more than one file's owner with view outlet. Here's a picture

[image: Multiple views in a NIB.]
Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwSAq.jpg

Also, even if I bind my outlets mentioned above with the right view, I can't get "outlet".bounds.size.width result from PumpController. self.view.bounds.size.width gives me the result of the File's owner view, not the result of PumpController view.

I need some help to explain me how to setup each of my custom views to each NSViewController in order to get this works.

Sorry for my english :s

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it as follows:

- In your main XIB place `NSBox` instances (with no border and heading) wherever you want your ViewController's views to be displayed.
- Connect the boxes to File's Owner by `IBOutlets`.
- In the File's Owner of that XIB (likely = AppDelegate) instantiate your `NSViewControllers` and set the `contentView` properties of the NSBox instances to the `view` properties of the `NSViewControllers`. Like so: `[self.leftBox setContentView:[yourViewController view]]`.

Comment: That worked! However, I think I'm gonna rewrite my app to divide views into one nib for each of them. So it'll easier to work with IB and file's owner. Thanks!